# production.ERROR: Method [getContent] does not exist on view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project based on laravel 5.5, When I use the command php artisan serve, my website is not running on localhost, and I'm getting the following in my error.log file.

> {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0):
>
> Method [getContent] does not exist on view. at
>   /home/lord/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:399)

The following is the codesegment of `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:399`

```
    /**
     * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (! Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
        }

        return $this->with(Str::camel(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Method must start with "with".

Comment: This is most likely a composer issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Get the view contents as html? Or does the error happen when you load a basic view?

Comment: The error happens when I load a basic view. However the issue is resolved when I login as an admin and then open the website again in a new tab

Comment: I cross checked with another local host where the same website is running fine, but my vendor is missing some files, which may possible be the reason of error. I tired to reinstall composer, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the rest of the exception trace? Do you have your encouragement files on the remote? Gave you cleared the cache for config, view and route?

Comment: Okay, so I was able to resolve the issue, there was this piece of code that had accidentally switched on the maintenance mode for the project. That pretty much explained why the admin mode was the only accessible mode.. Thanks a lot @fflabs!!

Comment: Nice finding! I always thought maintenance mode would degrade  gracefully  to a minimal page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere it's calling `getContent()` on the view. The problem is... Views don't have said method, that instead does exist in the Response class, because it extends from Symfony's [Http-Foundation Response Class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#component-foundation-attributes), which defines a protected `$content` property that is a string with, well, the response content.

The [View class in Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e3e8d585dcfab5abe6261b060f4df0d48f9924bf/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L135) has a `getContents` method, but if you aren't calling `getContent` in your code, then it meaningless to look for a typo.

The flow that precedes the error is:

Somewhere the method `getContents()` is called on the View, either directly or through the Facade.

Since the view doesn't have such method, the magic method `_call` [handles it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e3e8d585dcfab5abe6261b060f4df0d48f9924bf/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L396). The method as of Laravel 5.5 was:

```
/**
 * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (! Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
    }

    return $this->with(Str::camel(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
}
```

(In Laravel 6.x it also checks for a macro with the undefined method that has been called)

That code means that, if you call, for example

```
return view('userList')->withAvatarList([$avatar1, $avatar2]);
```

- Since that method does not exist, it forwards to _call as `_call('withAvatarList',[ [$avatar1, $avatar2 ] ]);`

  - if the method doesn't start with **with** (e.g `getAvatarList`) it will throw.
- since it *does* start with **with** then it will set a parameter on the view (because it's a container and can hold arbitrary data)

  - extract the part that comes after `with` (`withAvatarList` becomes `AvatarList`)
  - use Str facade to format it as camelCase, (`AvatarList` becodes `avatarList`)
  - Sets the `avatarList` parameter in the view as the argument you called the method

So in the end it's like you called

```
 return  view('userlist')->with('avatarList',[...]);
```

As said above, method starting with `get` will throw.

**Edit**

My best guess was a typo in your code or an unlikely error on the caches. You said it was because of maintenance mode. However `php artisan down` does not cause an error. It returns a header 503 and a simple message.

I believe maintenance mode overlapped with another circumstance.

Comment: That's quite understandable, but can you offer a solution? My composer seems to be the one that's misbehaving, and reinstalling isn't helping as well.. composer version is 1.9.3

Comment: Crap, that was meant to be a comment. This mobile app isn't made for clumsy fingers

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally switched on the maintenance mode for my project, and that was the reason for the error..

Comment: If you run `artisan cache:clear && artisan view:clear && artisan route:clear` and turn maintenance mode on again, does the error reappear? I believe it won't